# Скорость работы с большой таблицей MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Как увеличить скорость работы таблицы с 150к строк?
Индексы по полям проставил, но всё ровно скорость не такая как должна быть.

vps — [Виртуальный выделенный сервер VPS-2 от REG.RU](http://hosting.reg.ru/vps/vps_details?plan=VPS-2-1011).

Запросы:

```
SELECT * FROM audio ORDER BY ts desc LIMIT 0, 100
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM audio LIMIT 0, 100
```

Структура таблицы:

[image]

**Добавлено.**

И еще, на всех страницах сайта есть такой запрос - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM audio WHERE ts >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())`.
Добавил его в кеш, сайт залетал, предлагайте ускорение этого запроса.

Comment: mysql спокойно работает с миллионами записей, проблема либо в запросе, либо в сервере, либо в БД. Других вариантов нет и быть не может

Comment: 150K записей в одной таблице для MySQL это шелуха... Проблема может быть в запросе, в сервере, настройке MySQL, да и еще - какой тип БД используется. Показывайте запрос и как вы его используете.

Comment: У меня была когда-то проблема с очень медленным запросом. Так в том запросе, база вычисляла ячейку в каждой строке (делила на число) и сравнивала. У вас не так?

Comment: Поглядел ссылку на VPS... Уважаемый, если вы от этого VPS ожидаете умопомрачительных скоростей и в довесок на ней еще и Web-сервер я вас разочарую, а если Ваша база еще и в InnoDB, то о скорости вообще можно забыть. Но, все таки ждем запроса и подробностей...

Comment: "а если Ваша база еще и в InnoDB, то о скорости вообще можно забыть"

Мир слухами полниться... Самое страшное что многие в них верят, да еще потом и пропагандируют то, что не является правдой (или не совсем является правдой).

@Shamanis - побаловались бы вы реальными тестами перед тем как постить "аффтаритетнае мнение массы" и светить свою безукорезненую привязанность к стадному инстинкту.

Comment: Сколько занимают

    SELECT * FROM audio ORDER BY ts asc LIMIT 0, 100

и 

    SELECT * FROM audio ORDER BY ts desc LIMIT 0, 100

Comment: Мало, косяк был в запросе с timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Измените тип поля `ts` с `varchar(255)` на `int` или `bigint`, и вы, весьма вероятно, не поверите результатам...
2. Индекс с поля `status`, скорее всего, лучше убрать...
3. ИМХО: поле `artist` лучше сделать ссылкой на отдельную таблицу

Comment: Спасибо за советы.

Comment: Спасибо всем! 

<!-- время генерации: 0.00587, запросов к mysql: 1, запросов к парсеру: 1, запросов к кешу: 3 --> Теперь кул!

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что ваш MySQL крутится на дефолтном `my.cnf`. А там, как известно, памяти выделено как кот наплакал.

Comment: Ну я там что-то менял.

Comment: Что-то это конечно очень курто. Надо бы грамотно.